# Django 502 after changing app model, admin or view Nginx Gunicorn

Tags: python, django, nginx, gunicorn, digital-ocean

I have created a Django project which works perfectly when I run it local with `python3 manage.py runserver`.
These are the steps I took:
1. I Created a Droplet with a Django oneclick install image on DigitalOcean. (Everything works perfect)
2. I uploaded my project and changed the Nginx Configuration and gunicorn.conf (502 error)

/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/django:

```
upstream app_server {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server ipv6only=on;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index index.html index.htm;

    client_max_body_size 4G;
    server_name _;

    keepalive_timeout 5;

    # Your Django project's media files - amend as required
    location /media  {
        alias /home/django/gezelligehotelletjes_media;
    }

    # your Django project's static files - amend as required
    location /static {
        alias /home/django/gezelligehotelletjes_static;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://app_server;
    }
}
```

/etc/init/gunicorn.conf

```
description "Gunicorn daemon for Django project"

start on (local-filesystems and net-device-up IFACE=eth0)
stop on runlevel [!12345]

# If the process quits unexpectedly trigger a respawn
respawn

setuid django
setgid django
chdir /home/django

exec gunicorn \
    --name=gezelligehotelletjes \
    --pythonpath=gezelligehotelletjes \
    --bind=0.0.0.0:9000 \
    --config /etc/gunicorn.d/gunicorn.py \
    gezelligehotelletjes.wsgi:application
```

/etc/gunicorn.d/gunicorn.py:

```
"""gunicorn WSGI server configuration."""
from multiprocessing import cpu_count
from os import environ


def max_workers():
    return cpu_count() * 2 + 1

max_requests = 1000
worker_class = 'gevent'
workers = max_workers()
```

So I figured, there is probably something wrong with my project.

3. I made a copy of the original Django-project, renamed everything in the project to 'gezelligehotelletjes' ,uploaded it to the server and restarted Gunicorn `sudo service gunicorn restart` (Worked like a charm.)
4. I copied one of the apps to the new project, uploaded it, restarted Gunicorn. (502 Error)
5. Removed the app and created a new one with `python3 manage.py startapp base`, uploaded it and restarted Gunicorn. (Works like a charm)
6. Copied the files (models.py, admin.py, views.py) from the original base app to the base app in the new project. (502 Error)
7. Removed all the code from the files, except for the first imports, uploaded it and restarted Gunicorn. (Works like a charm.)
8. Tried to find some info online, repeated this, and once again.

These are the errors I keep getting in nginx/error.log

```
2015/12/26 03:02:10 [error] 991#0: *86 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 95.96.206.181, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:9000/", host: "188.166.70.238"
2015/12/26 03:21:10 [error] 991#0: *90 recv() failed (104: Connection reset by peer) while reading response header from upstream, client: 95.96.206.181, server: _, request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:9000/", host: "188.166.70.238"
```

==========EDIT===============
Django settings file

```
import os
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__))
SECRET_KEY = '[secret key]'
DEBUG = False    
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = ["*", ]

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'base',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'gezelligehotelletjes.urls'    
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'gezelligehotelletjes.wsgi'

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': '[db name]',
        'USER': '[username]',
        'PASSWORD': '[user password]',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'    
TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'    
USE_I18N = True    
USE_L10N = True    
USE_TZ = True

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# ==================== PyUploadCare ====================
# https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/pyuploadcare/v1.1/pyuploadcare.pdf
UPLOADCARE = {
    'pub_key': '[pyuploadcare pub_key]',
    'secret': '[pyuploadcare secret_key]'
}    
UPLOADCARE_LOCALE = "nl"
```

wsgi.py:

```
import os
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "gezelligehotelletjes.settings")

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

manage.py

```
import os
import sys

if __name__ == "__main__":
    os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "gezelligehotelletjes.settings")

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

I have been trying to get my Django project online for weeks now and it is starting to drive me crazy.
So I really hope someone could help me out here.

Comment: Try changing `proxy_pass` to `http://<your_IP_address>:9000`.

Comment: @RahulGupta I have changed the `proxy pass` to both `http://188.166.70.238:9000` and `188.166.70.238:9000` but I still get a `502 Bad Gateway`

Comment: Can you enable logging in Gunicorn? That will show you the exact error so we can help you better. Also, by the looks of it it's some kind of ORM related issue, as an app with models doesn't work but an app without models does work - can you also check DB settings?

Comment: @AndreiAvram I have been able to fix it by just dumping everything and starting over from scratch. Now the site is live.